# Running a standalone postgres instance alongside existing servers

Tags: postgresql

I'm developing an application that heavily relies on Postgres. Currently, users are required to have Postgres set up and place database credentials in a config file that my app reads.

There are a couple of issues with the approach which I am not entirely happy with:

- I can't dictate the version of Postgres to use (they may need a certain version for some other task)
- Users have to install a separate piece of software before they can use my application.
- They would need to provide database credentials to my app (which they may revoke later)
- Potentially issues with database name conflicts

Is it possible to run a standalone version of Postgres i.e running it from a folder and potentially alongside another version of Postgres on the same machine?

My current solution is to run it as a docker instance, this avoids any conflicts with data and permissions but does not solve the problem of needing users to install a separate piece of software first.

The application is completely standalone and single user and there is never a need for a user to interact with the database directly, even actions like taking backups is handled by the app, which internally calls pg_dump

(I would have thought something like this would be possible for the people who develop Postgres - I can't imagine they constantly install and remove the software completely from their system in order to test things.)

Comment: Sure. Just put the binaries where you want, put settings how you want, and run it when you want. There’s nothing special there

Comment: If you want to run another PostgreSQL server on the same machine, you should change the port number in the `postgresql.conf` file and tell your application to connect to that port (instead of 5432 by default).

Comment: Your last sentence is baffling. As a PostgreSQL developer, what kind of things do you think I test which require me to have PostgreSQL *not* installed?  If I do want a clean box for some reason (which I sometimes do, but almost never when I'm wearing my PostgreSQL developer hat), I just go start one on AWS.

Comment: @Bruno  Instead of choosing a different port, you could not specify any listen_addresses and use the unix-domain socket exclusively.  Then it wouldn't matter if the port is the same, as long as the socket directory is different.  That used to not work in Windows, but as of recently I understand that it does.

Comment: @jjanes You could, but the socket name is based on the port number (`.s.PGSQL.nnnn`), but you can indeed change `unix_socket_directories` too to have it in a different location. It looks like you're right, there's been a patch for `AF_UNIX` socket support on Windows, I'm not sure if it's made it into the PostgreSQL 13 release (not tried).

Comment: For applications like this, people often use SQLite or similar. That would be my first choice. But if you really need PostgreSQL, it almost seems like you'd need to roll your own custom installer that would install PostgreSQL. Shudder.